# create a ListBox inside an UserControl and bind objects

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to create a ListBox inside a UserContorl, and than, using that userControl to show and "manage" that list in many pages.

For example i got a list of trucks, each object truck has some property like the name, the id...

Now i create my own UserControl

```
<UserControl
x:Class="Crud.View.ListboxInUserControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Crud.View"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Name="myUserControl"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <ListBox x:Name="aName" ItemsSource="{Binding ??}">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Id"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

How can i bind the items in the code behind?

And how can i manage the "click" on the list?

In a Page.xaml i want to write something like

```
<LUC:ListboxInUserControl x:Name="MyListbox DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

and in the code behind

```
private ObservableCollection<Truck> TestList { get; set; }
...
TestList = await TruckService.GetAll(); //a method to get the list 
MyListbox.MyItemsSource = TestList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add listbox to your UserControl,

```
 <ListBox x:Name="aName" SelectionChanged="aName_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Id"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,20,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Add event handler for getting selection changed and public property of listbox to bind objects in user control code behind,

```
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SelectionChangedEvent;

    public ListBoxInUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void aName_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SelectionChangedEvent(sender, new EventArgs());
    }


    private ListBox myVar;

    public ListBox MyProperty
    {
        get { return aName; }
        set { aName = value; }
    }
```

Then you can add this usercontrol in your xaml,

```
   <local:ListBoxInUserControl x:Name="uc_ListBoxInUserControl"       SelectionChangedEvent="uc_ListBoxInUserControl_SelectionChangedEvent">  </local:ListBoxInUserControl>
```

In code behind you can bind data ,

```
 uc_ListBoxInUserControl.MyProperty.ItemsSource = TestList;
```

and access selection changed event,

```
 private void uc_ListBoxInUserControl_SelectionChangedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```